# Chrome Extension execute script doesn't render browser content value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

All I am trying to do change the value of popup.html on the basis of Specific URL. So I am sending message to background.js when user click on change ID of H2 from popup.html render the content by using specific JavaScript file

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Helpfullio",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
          "*://google.com/*/*",
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
    <h2 id="change">Change ___________</h2> 
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
    </html>
```

**popup.js**

```
    function clickHandler(e) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click"}, function(response) {
            // this.close(); finishes processing request
        });
    }


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    })
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {
        case "popup-click":
          chrome.tabs.query({
            'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true
            }, function (tabs) {
                var url = tabs[0].url;
                var result = url.split('/');
                var hostname = result[2];
                if("bitlock" == hostname){
                  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
                      file: "render.js",
                      // allFrames: true
                  });
                }else{
                   hrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
                      file: "secondrender.js",
                      // allFrames: true
                  }); 
                }
            sendResponse({});
          });
        break;

        default:
            alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to background.js from " + sender);
        }
    }
);;
```

JavaScript doesn't render the content of popup.html as it is not finding the elementID "change" . SO here how can I give reference of popup.html file in render.js file

**render.js**

```
document.getElementById("change").textContent = 'new text';
```

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript runs a content script in a web page tab, not in the browserAction popup. See [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: You don't want render.js, you should put that code in an message event listener in popup.js and instead of executeScript in background, send a specific message to the popup